# Falha de Tradução/Layout no anúncio da newsletter

Tags: bug, tradução, internacionalização, design

Ao abrir uma dúvida, esta `<div id="newsletter-ad">` é apresentado ao lado direito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso o correto seria traduzir o "Love this site?" e o botão para Registro está maior que a `div` principal.